# How to search string to find data after end of pattern of characters (SQL DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I need to find the next single event that appears after the last occurrence of the following pattern of events "5065|5373|5373".  My problem is that the pattern can be in the string 1 to n times.  Here's an example of the some data that I have to search through.

The events in **BOLD** are what i would be looking for.

5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|**5509**|5329|5321
5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|**5509**|5270|5373|5373|5373|5080|5081|5013|5040|5295|5321
5065|5373|5373|**5295**|5323|5321

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SUBSTR, INSTR, STRLEN are your friends.

Comment: I've been able to use a substring function with a locate to find the next event, but it only returns the next event of the first occurrence of the pattern.  If the string has more than one pattern I don't know how to skip the previous patterns to find the final. SUBSTR(M.PATH_2,LOCATE('5065|5373|5373',M.PATH_2)+5,4) as NEXTEVENT

Comment: What version of DB2, and is the data how is this data actually stored?

Comment: X-Zero, Version DB2 v9.5.0.7.  The data is stored as a string of text.  The data in the posted question is a cut and paste from a result set.

Comment: Also, what happens if the pattern is the last thing in the string - that is, there's no data _after_ the pattern?  Should that one be excluded, should it return `null`, or what?

Comment: In our application it would be impossible to not have data after the pattern.  These are events in an IVR and even if they hung up we tag an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't create a new stored procedure or UDF, here's a recursive query that'll do it for you:

```
WITH Recurs(id, index, token, source) as (
            SELECT id, LOCATE('5065|5373|5373|', M.PATH_2), '', M.PATH_2
            FROM M
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT id, LOCATE('5065|5373|5373|', source, index + 15), 
            SUBSTR(source, index + 15, 4), source
            FROM Recurs
            WHERE index > 0)
SELECT * 
FROM Recurs
WHERE index = 0
```

Which yields the expected:

```
ID  INDEX   TOKEN  SOURCE 
3   0       5295   5065|5373|5373|5295|5323|5321     
2   0       5509   5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5509|5270|5373|5373|5373|5080|5081|5013|5040|5295|5321
1   0       5509   5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5509|5329|5321
```

Comment: X-Zero, it's almost working, but I may be doing something wrong because I'm getting less 5 less records than when I run the first part of the select above the UNION ALL.  I'm trying to get some help from people that know more than me that might be able to tweak your query a little more to make it work.  I'll update as soon as I figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One fairly straightforward way to do this is with a recursive common table expression (CTE):

```
CREATE FUNCTION localutil.locatelastmatch(
       searchparm VARCHAR(4000), inputparm VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS SMALLINT
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN
WITH rcurs(counter, output ) AS (
    VALUES (0,0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT counter+1, LOCATE(searchparm,inputparm,counter+1) 
       FROM rcurs
       WHERE counter < LENGTH(inputparm) AND counter < 32767
    )
SELECT MAX(output) FROM rcurs
;
```

It may not be the cheapest way to find the last matching occurrence, but it's at least a contender for it. By burying the complexity into a scalar user-defined function (UDF), you won't have to introduce the SQL recursion into every query that needs to search for the last instance of a pattern.

Here's how it works against your sample strings:

```
WITH originput(val) as (VALUES
('5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5509|5329|5321'),
('5065|5373|5373|5065|5373|5373|5509|5270|5373|5373|5373|5080|5081|5013|5040|5295|5321'),
('5065|5373|5373|5295|5323|5321')
)
SELECT LENGTH(val) AS inputlength, 
    localutil.locatelastmatch( '5065|5373|5373|', val ) AS finaloffset,
    SUBSTR(val, localutil.locatelastmatch( '5065|5373|5373|', val ) 
    + LENGTH( '5065|5373|5373|' ), 4) AS nextitem
FROM originput
;

INPUTLENGTH FINALOFFSET NEXTITEM
----------- ----------- --------
         59          31 5509
         84          16 5509
         29           1 5295
```

Comment: While I agree that this is something that should probably be made into a UDF, you should look into tweaking your example a bit.  For example, there's at least a couple of options you should place on there, to enable (potentially) speedier processing.  Also, you're likely to get the desired `output` row long before `counter` finishes it's counting - have `LOCATE` do your incrementation for you.